# Xslt recursive transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, grouping, siblings

I've tried in all ways but I got no result. How can I tranform - with XSLT - a XML like this:

```
<root>
     <row>topic</row>
     <row>Topic1</row>
     <row>words</row>
     <row>word1</row>
     <row>word2</row>
     <row>word3</row>
     <row>words</row>
     <row>word4</row>
     <row>word5</row>
     <row>word6</row>
     <row>topic</row>
     <row>Topic2</row>
     <row>words</row>
     <row>word7</row>
     <row>word8</row>
     <row>word9</row>
     <row>topic</row>
     <row>Topic3</row>
     <row>words</row>
     <row>word10</row>
     <row>word11</row>
     <row>word12</row>
</root>
```

In a XML like this?

```
<topic>Topic1
    <words>word1word2word3word4word5word6</words>
</topic>
<topic>Topic2
    <words>word7word8word9</words>
</topic>
<topic>Topic3
    <words>word10word11word12</words>
</topic>
```

'topic' and 'words' value regularly occur in the XML and I would group first by topic and in each topic group the words by 'words'...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it supports XSLT 2.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could so simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-starting-with="row[.='topic']">
            <topic>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/>
                <words>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[position() gt 3]" separator=""/>
                </words>
            </topic>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what if instead of <row>Topic1</row> or <row>Topic2</row> I had <row><cell>a</cell><cell>b</cell><cell>c</cell></row> etc? How can I output the every single cell in a <newcell> element? @michael.hor257k

Comment: @AmintaCode I don't see the connection to the current question. Why don't you post a new one?

Comment: Ok, thanks, you're right! However I used `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]/cell" />` to output the values....

Comment: Ah, now I get it (I think). It's very difficult to read code in comments, esp. partial code.

Comment: I think that maybe it would be useful to know how to get the same result without using <xsl:for-each-group>, is it possible? @michael.hor257k

Comment: This is a grouping problem and XSLT 2.0 has a tool for grouping. I see no reason to look for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I see you're very clever in Xslt, I wonder if you want to take a look at another question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794064/avoid-duplicated-attributes-names-with-xslt-xpath. @michael.hor257k