# Avoid duplicated attributes names with XSLT/ XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xpath, duplicates

Say I have an XML like that:

```
<parole>
   <parola id="a">1</parola>
   <parola id="b">2</parola>
   <parola id="c">3</parola>
   <parola id="a">4</parola>
   <parola id="a">5</parola>
   <parola id="b">6</parola>
</parole>
```

Now, I know that the `generate-id()` function exists. But, for a learning purpose, I would like to know how to change with XSLT the values of the attributes called "id".

I've thought about an "algorithm" like:

> consider the following and the preceding sibling of an attribute.
>   If you meet a duplicate of the present attribute, add "f" to the end of this name and (recursively) add another "f" until we have no more attributes with the same value.

So my final XML would be like:

```
<parole>
  <parola id="a">1</parola>
  <parola id="b">2</parola>
  <parola id="c">3</parola>
  <parola id="af">4</parola>
  <parola id="aff">5</parola>
  <parola id="bf">6</parola>
</parole>
```

Now, I've tried to get this result with a recursive function like:

```
<xsl:variable name="following-siblings-ids" select="/parole/parola/following-sibling::parola/@id"/>
<xsl:variable name="preceding-siblings-ids" select="/parole/parola/preceding-sibling::parola/@id"/>

<xsl:function name="du:check" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="id" /> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$id  = $following-siblings-ids and $preceding-siblings-ids">
            <xsl:value-of select="du:check(concat($id, 'f'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="parola">
  <xsl:value-of select="du:check(@id)"/>
</xsl:template match="parola">
```

But I get a result like

> "af" "bf" "cf" "af" "af" "bf"

instead of the the desired one.

Any hints? This would be a simple task in a non-declarative language with dynamic variables and `for-each`s, but I don't know how to realize it in XSLT...

Comment: Shouldn't the first line in your sample document have the id *a* instead of *af*?

Comment: You should probably count the preceding @id's identical to the current and add as many f's at the end. The point you're probably not hitting is where you write "(recursively) add another f", that would mean you have to run this *n* times on the result of the previous iteration (but there probably is another error in your logic)

Comment: Yes, corrected, @Markus

Comment: You should make a test to see what your variables contain. It looks like you think they contain an expression. That is not so: they contain the result of evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1 solution. The following transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- standard copy template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="make-f">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">f<xsl:call-template name="make-f">
    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parola/@id">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="f">
      <xsl:call-template name="make-f">
    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="count(../preceding-sibling::parola/@id[.=$id])"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $f)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input sample, produces the following output:

```
$ xsltproc test.xsl test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parole>
  <parola id="a">1</parola>
  <parola id="b">2</parola>
  <parola id="c">3</parola>
  <parola id="af">4</parola>
  <parola id="aff">5</parola>
  <parola id="bf">6</parola>
</parole>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a key to "group" the elements by the id attribute and then identify the position in that group to append an index or if you want the number of `f` letters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="n" select="'f'"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:node-index-of" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:param name="sequence" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="for $pos in 1 to count($sequence) return $pos[$node is $sequence[$pos]]"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="p-by-id" match="parola" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="parola[not(. is key('p-by-id', @id)[1])]/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat(., string-join(for $i in 1 to mf:node-index-of(.., key('p-by-id', .)) - 1 return $n, ''))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template with `match="@* | node()"` is the so called identity transformation template that copies everything unchanged level by level, allowing us to add further templates for the nodes we want to transform.

The only node you want to transform is the `id` attribute of `parola` elements where more than one exists with a certain id value, so I have written a template `match="parola[not(. is key('p-by-id', @id)[1])]/@id"` for that, using a key `<xsl:key name="p-by-id" match="parola" use="@id"/>` to identify all elements with the same value.

The new attribute value `concat(., string-join(for $i in 1 to mf:node-index-of(.., key('p-by-id', .)) - 1 return $n, ''))` is then computed by concatenating the existing value with a sequence containing `$n` one less that the number of times of the positional index of the parent `parola` in its group.

If you are new to XSLT and XPath 2.0 take some time to read up in a tutorial or book on the identity transformation, keys, and user defined functions.

Comment: Please can you explain your solution piecemeal? I would be very grateful @martin-honnen